# Concatenating three numpy arrays and writing them to a file

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file that I'm reading in with three columns that look like this:

```
01 29 54.288
01 48 23.384
01 56 42.495
.. .. ......
```

I need to take these three numbers, do some math with the third column to round it off to an integer, and then write them to a new file so they look like this:

```
01295
01482
01564
```

Simplified code:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt(filename,dtype=str)

ra1 = data[:,1]
ra2 = data[:,2]
ra3 = data[:,3]

# This part is because ra3 is in arcseconds, it's correct, just here for reference
ra3 = ra3.astype(float)
ra3n = ra3/60 * 10
ra3n = np.rint(ra3n)

ra = ra1+ra2+ra3n

print ra
```

Yields the error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I've also attempted to use `np.concatenate`, but this does not seem to do what I want, unless I'm using it wrong. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at np.hstack(). http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are trying to string-add all the arrays `ra1`, `ra2`, and `ra3n`. The problem is that you can't add strings like that in numpy. First, you need to convert `ra3n` to an array of strings:

```
ra3n = ra3n.astype(str)
```

Then, a better approach would be to use something like `zip()` and `.join()` to help you out:

```
final_list = np.array(["".join(elem) for elem in zip(ra1, ra2, ra3n)])
```

And then you can write `final_list` to a file as normal.

Comment: Worked like a charm, you're a legend, mate. Thanks!